# Mouse teleports

Tags: mouse

The mouse cursor worked fine when I was on the NOOBS interface with the OS selection. After I installed Raspbian and went into the GUI of Raspbian the cursor's starting location is in the center of the screen but when I move the mouse it seemingly teleported to the bottom of the screen and could not be brought back up.

Comment: have you tried a different mouse?

Comment: No I have not. I was just wondering why it happened. It seemed as if the GUI was like a second Window that the mouse could not go into. I was able to drag the cursor across horizontally along the bottom, but each time I attempted to drag it upwards the cursor would teleport back.

Comment: This almost sounds like the mouse battery is dying **or** something is taking a lot of RAM on your Pi. Are you running any software that takes a lot of RAM? You can run `top` to see if anything is.

Comment: Power issue with the mouse. As lenik suggested... try another mouse. I had a similar issue with cheap mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if [this tweak](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/121) would help improve things at all.